# Android xml android:layout_width attribute unknown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

What is the use of defining width of a view like this :

android:layout_width="UNKNOWN_DATA_0x1"

I saw somewhere but when tried to use, it shows cannot resolve symbol.
So , how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

you seen this type of width of view in Decompile APK's Layout File so,
use as below :

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```